# Java application on Mac OS X does not always receive open file events from the OS

Tags: java, macos, event-handling

My java application's main class has a static initializer where we set up the ApplicationAdapter to listen for notifications from the OS, before main() is invoked. Up to now, this has worked as expected. However, lately (since 10.7? not sure as to the timeline), sometimes this does not work. After debugging the app, it *seems* as though the OS is posting the file open event asynchronously on the event thread while the static initializer is still running. So sometimes the initialization completes before the file open event is posted (and the file is opened correctly) and other times, the event is posted before initialization is complete (i.e. before my app has a chance to register an ApplicationListener) and so my app never gets the chance to process the event, and the requested document is not opened.

Has anyone else come across this problem?

One possible solution I've tried is to pause the event queue as at the beginning of the main class's static initializer, something like:

```
static{
    final Object monitor = new Object();
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable(){
       public void run(){
            synchronized( monitor) {
                try{ monitor.wait(); } catch( Exception e ){ e.printStackTrace(); }
            }
       }
    });

    registerApplicationListener();

    synchronized( monitor) {
        try{ monitor.notifyAll(); }
        catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}
```

This blocks event dispatch while the application initialization sets up the ApplicationListener to receive OS events. However, the problem remains that the OS could still dispatch the events before the initialization is complete, and there's nothing I can do about that, as far as I can tell. Nothing in the Apple Java extensions API indicates any way to control event dispatch behaviour. I also have not been able to find any way of controlling any aspects of event dispatch via a configuration in Info.plist.

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed that this is a file open event coming from the OS X shell.  Java applications cant catch this notification reliably and a workaround is to install a launch daemon to catch the notification and forward to the application as startup params.

Registering a URL scheme for the app might also work but Ive never tried it with a Java app hopefully the params would come to the main() args

Comment: If the event is dispatched in the event thread asynchronously, it might occur before initialization is complete. What I don't know for sure is whether or not this is, in fact, happening. Since I can't debug the Apple java extensions code, I can't know this for sure, but it's the only diagnosis I have.

Comment: As for your second comment, that's exactly my problem (and yes, I'm well aware of how event dispatch works). What I'm trying to find out is a) if anyone else has encountered this problem (and what advice, if any, they might have) and b) is there any configuration setting (in the Info.plist, for instance) that controls entry point behaviour for java application.

Comment: Yes, that is, in fact, exactly what I'm trying to have happen - hence the initialization takes place in the static initializer, so that the moment the main class is reference, all this set up is taken care of.

Comment: Yeah, but that main() isn't invoked directly, though. The application stub actually instantiates the main class, then invokes main() via reflection.

Comment: Doesnt matter.  If you want to catch these kind of events before your app runs, create a daemon process to catch them and launch your app with startup params.

Comment: I *know* you can't catch an event before the app is initialized - what I don't know is if events are being dispatched before initialization. If they are, then, yes, I have no hope of catching them. I get it.

Comment: Sorry I guess I didnt get your exact issue

Comment: It just seems like weak design to me to start dispatching events to applications without ensuring that they've had a chance to initialize properly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16793/discussion-between-stackmonster-and-javagrendel)